# Where can I ask questions about nutritional info?

Tags: discussion, nutrition

I tried to post a question about the nutritional information for a specific food but apparently that violates the rules of this area of Stack Exchange. Can someone please point me to a place where I would be able to ask and receive an answer to questions related to nutrition values?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is not for questions on where a subject would be on-topic.  Such a question might be on on-topic in a Meta section.  The Stack Exchange does not have a site that caters to general nutritional information questions and attempts to create one in the past have failed.

Comment: This is probably the largest food and nutrient database freely available on the internet: https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/ . It has a huge list of foods with a detailed nutrient content and a list of nutrients with foods high or low in a given nutrient.

Answer (score 2):

Nutrition was originally on topic, however due to various reasons it was removed as on topic except when specifically in the context of supporting a fitness program.

Similarly, sites such as Medical Sciences, Cooking also severely restrict questions about nutrition, and there isn't currently a stack exchange site that allows general nutrition questions.

There have been a few nutrition proposals on Area 51, however they have rarely made it to even private beta, and as far as I know, none have made it to a public beta stage.